# Is it possible to hide the "Copy To" and "Move To" context menus?

Tags: nautilus

I've just read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/5054/1231) and realized that I had never used either the "Copy To" or "Move To" context menu - is it possible to hide them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to do this in either 12.04 or 12.10, because of the changes to `Nautilus` and the removal of `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml`. It has been asked very recently (June 2012) in the [gnome nautilus](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2012-June/msg00009.html) mailing lists, and it is clear from the developers' responses that one would now have to download the source code, patch it, and then recompile it to eliminate or hide the *copy to* and *move to* menus.

[Emmanuel Bassi](http://blogs.gnome.org/ebassi/), a gnome developer, [responded](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2012-June/msg00009.html) to the same request on the mailing list by noting that:

> The UI definitions are part of the application:
>   modifying them is the equivalent of modifying the binary on disk.

In another [response](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2012-June/msg00013.html), Emmanuel goes into more detail and points out that:

> It's not possible because now (in the interest of relocatability
>   of the application, and to improve the startup time) the UI
>   description file is "compiled" inside the binary itself; the UI
>   description file is only available in the Git repository, and every
>   change requires recompiling Nautilus.
>
> Given that editing the UI file once installed was never a supported
>   action for the reasons I pointed out in this thread, this is not a
>   break in functionality.
>
> What you want to achieve cannot be done with the current, or any
>   future, version of Nautilus; the only way to do it is to actually
>   modify Nautilus so that it can do what you want.

This is the **official** position on `Nautilus`, and so the only thing to do is to suggest a patch, or simply prepare your own patch and build your own custom version. The source code that you need is available from the [git repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/).

There is no dirty 'hack' that can accomplish what you want at the moment, as the developers have explained. It may change in the future, but this is the current state of affairs.

Answer (score 13):

#### For 11.10 and earlier

Yes, edit the file:

```
/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml
```

and find the **last** instance of this:

```
    <menu action="CopyToMenu">
        <menuitem name="Copy to next pane" action="Copy to next pane"/>
        <menuitem name="Copy to Home" action="Copy to Home"/>
        <menuitem name="Copy to Desktop" action="Copy to Desktop"/>
    </menu>
    <menu action="MoveToMenu">
        <menuitem name="Move to next pane" action="Move to next pane"/>
        <menuitem name="Copy to Home" action="Move to Home"/>
        <menuitem name="Copy to Desktop" action="Move to Desktop"/>
    </menu>
```

and make the insides empty like this:

```
    <menu action="CopyToMenu">
    </menu>
    <menu action="MoveToMenu">
    </menu>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: In case the order of the nodes is changed in the future, the one with elements that need to be removed (or commented out) is `<popup name="selection"> ... </popup>`.

Comment: Wow, this answer was very, very helpful! I can now RULE THE WORLD! I HAVE INFINITE POWER!!! (Seriously, thanks. The ability to completely customize the context menus will be very handy.)

Comment: Not good for multi-user systems

Comment: Is that supposed to work with 12.04 ? Because I don't have a **/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml** file.

Comment: @user55822 The same problem in 12.10. Because of that, this question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation - the current answer is out-of-date and does not apply to the recent Ubuntu versions.