# How to remove items from the Nautilus context menu?

Tags: nautilus, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to hide the “Copy To” and “Move To” context menus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5055/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-copy-to-and-move-to-context-menus)

It used to be possible to [edit `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml` in order to do that](https://askubuntu.com/q/5055/1231), but there is no such file in Ubuntu 12.10.

How to remove from the Nautilus context menu the following items?

- Copy to
- Move to
- Tags

Comment: I've added a bounty on that question to get an answer for 12.10.

Comment: @JorgeCastro A new answer was posted to that question. Is there a way to show that **both of them are correct** but apply to different versions of Ubuntu? I can mark only one answer as accepted.