# How do I reorder the Nautilus right-click menu?

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to reorder the *default items* in the Nautilus context menu?

e.g. when I right-click on an archive, the top item is "Open with Archive Manager" but way down the bottom is "Extract Here".

I would like to move the "Extract Here" item next to the "Open with Archive Manager" item as they are both actions that deal with the archive itself.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would make this even clearer. I like this type of usability question.

Comment: There is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3326507) related it. But now `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml` it is [**not available**](http://askubuntu.com/a/218446).

Comment: Based on [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5055/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-copy-to-and-move-to-context-menus) answer -the file/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml is now compiled in for speeed. So you will to make the changes to the source code of nautilus and recompile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the context menu in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus) and [How to get the Nautilus scripts working in 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-on-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: Neither of these are duplicate questions! The first one is about adding new items to the menu, the second one is about adding python scripts. I asked about re-ordering the existing menu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to do this, because of the changes to Nautilus and the removal of /usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml. It has been asked  (June 2012) in the gnome nautilus mailing lists, and it is clear from the developers' responses that one would now have to download the source code, patch it, and then recompile it to re-order menus.

Source: [Is it possible to hide the "Copy To" and "Move To" context menus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5055/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-copy-to-and-move-to-context-menus)